# Duplicate check in stored proc vs code

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have to check for duplicate user name  when creating a new user name.

I have two options

1. Create a stored procedure `IsDuplicateUserName` with parameter `username` that returns true or false.
2. Return count of user name from stored procedure and in c# if the user name count is more than 0 then return true in C# code.

Which one is better approach?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What if you get status back saying A userName is available and by the time this user send request to actually assign this user name another user has already snatched it? I would suggest Assigning a UserName yourself to a user just take their details and Make a user name your self and return it to user once it has been added to database.

Comment: podiluska 2 .. what approach would you suggest?

Comment: M. Ali, index is already there. I can't make user name myself as a requirement, so that closes that window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check at any point before creating the user, there is no guarantee that the username has not been created in the meantime - you create the potential for a "race condition"

The way you should guarantee the uniqueness of usernames is with a unique index/constraint.

If you wish to check beforehand as well, then either method is equally valid, depending on your religious viewpoint.

Comment: I Like it, I know index is required but, I wanted to check beforehand too. Thank you.

Comment: Given a **lot** of users, doing a check using `IF EXISTS(....)` could be a lot more efficient that using a `COUNT` which has to scan the whole table